# How can I make many runs of a simulation and plot all the results with one expression evaluation?

Tags: plotting, programming

I have many cells, starting with this first cell:

```
mcRun = 20;
randomWalk[n_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], n]; 

RandVar = Table[randomWalk[5], {mcRun}];
Length[RandVar] 
MatrixForm[RandVar[[1 ;; 10]]] (* only display first 10 *)
ListPlot[RandVar]
```

Then later in a 2nd cell:

```
CorRandVar = RandVar * 10;
```

Still later in a 3rd cell:

```
InvCor = CDF[NormalDistribution[], CorRandVar];
```

And there are many more cells that depend on the value of the initial parameter `mcRun` that I defined in the first cell.

At the moment I use 'Evaluate Notebook' to get my results. I wait for one 'Evaluate Notebook' to complete, note down the result from running with `mcRun = 20` (20 monte carlo simulations), edit `mcRun = 20` to another value and repeat.

So how could I automate what 'Evaluate Notebook' does and plot, for example, `InvCor` (or any function/value) as a function of the input parameter `mcRun`, say, from 20 to 20,000? ? Or better, how could I incorporate my simulation into a `Manipulate` to add interactivity?

Comment: Hi @Nasser M.Abbasi I know how to do an Evaluate Notebook command as it calculates every cells within the Notebook. I want to Evaluate Notebook with mcRun=20, plot the result of InvCor at this setting, then mcRun=200 again, and plot the result of InvCor and so on. Maybe some sort of parametric list because I have lots of dependencies in my code, so I have to do Evaluate Notebook many times...or maybe someone knows an easier way than having to manually do Evaluate Notebook many times?

Answer (score 5):

You might write a master function, call it `runSim`, that evaluates all the functions you have already defined and takes the parameter needed to make a single run as it argument. Then evaluate

```
Map[runSim, {p1, p2, ... }]
```

to get several runs at once. If several parameters need to be given for a single run, then you would evaluate

```
MapThread[runSim, {{p11,p12, ...}, {p21, p22, ...}, ... }
```

#### Edit

As a concrete example, I have converted part of your code into a `runSim` function. I hope it will start you down the path to automating your evaluations.

```
randomWalk[n_] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], n]

runSim[runs_Integer] /; runs >= 10 := 
   Module[{randVar}, 
      randVar = Table[randomWalk[5], {runs}];
      Column[{MatrixForm[randVar[[1 ;; 10]]] ,
              ListPlot[randVar]}]]

runSim[10]
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi @m_goldberg thanks

Comment: Hi @m_goldberg, but what is by Evaluate NoteBook and I have to do this many times, how to plot something in this case?

Comment: @sebastianc. The function that automates your simulation runs can also plot the data created by the runs. It can plot the results one at a time as each simulation completes or it can collect the data into a data set where esch record is the data returned from one plot. It can then, if this is appropriate, plot all the records in one combined plot. The possibilities are endless. _Mathematica_ can do almost anything with data. But I can't advise on how to handle your data without knowing what you want to do with it. Just saying you want to plot it isn't enough.